# Expected value and variance of total value of 60 die rolls

Tags: probability, means, variance

I want to find the expected value and variance of the total spots from 60 fair die rolls.

The way I tried approaching this is we know that (if x = total value of all die rolls) that $P(x = 60) = (1/6)^{60}$ and $P(x=360) = (1/6)^{60}$ and then calculating $E(x) = 60*(1/6)^{60} + 360(1/6)^{60}$ which obviously comes up with a very small fraction.

How would one approach this problem? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If the rolls of the dice are independent, then you can solve the problem by finding the expected value and variance of a single roll, then multiplying by 60. (In fact, the independence is only needed for the variances to add.)